# Http get multiple json files from different API endpoints using node express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I'm looking into the most efficient way to get multiple JSON files from different API endpoints using node.

Basically i'd like to store each JSON object in a variable, and send them all to Jade template files for parsing.
I've got it setup working for getting **one single** JSON file (jsonFile1) by doing the following:

```
httpOptions = {
    host: 'api.test123.com',
    path : '/content/food/?api_key=1231241412',
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "GET",
    port: 80
}

var jsonFile1;

http.get(httpOptions, function(res) {
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        jsonFile1= JSON.parse(body)
        console.log("Got response: " + jsonFile1);
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});

app.set('views', __dirname);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
        data: jsonFile1
    });
});
```

But i don't really want to have to repeat all of this to get **multiple** json endpoints and send them to home jade template.

Any ideas to do this efficiently?

Comment: Put httpOptions for each endpoint in an array, loop through the array and make an http-request for each object, save the results in another array, render the template with the array.

Comment: Ahhh. Don't suppose there's any chance you can provide the code snippet?

Comment: Hmm sure I can provide a simple example, but in general it's easier if you show what you've tried/how you think you could solve the problem.

Comment: So @Scotty, I give you a hint, you want to see code, I take time to write you some code, and you don't accept my answer? Or give feedback as to why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, this is a quick example using the excellent [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

```
var async = require('async'),
    // Array of apis
    httpOptions = [
        {
            host: 'api.test123.com',
            path : '/content/food/?api_key=1231241412',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: "GET",
            port: 80
        },
            host: 'api.test234.com',
            path : '/content/food/?api_key=1231241412',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: "GET",
            port: 80
        }
    ];

// Put the logic for fetching data in its own function
function getFile(options, done) {
    http.get(options, function(res) {
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            done(null, JSON.parse(body));
            console.log("Got response: " + jsonFile1);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        done(e);
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
}


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // Map the options through the getFile function, resulting in an array of each response
    async.map(httpOptions, getFile, function (err, jsonFiles) {
        // You should probably check for any errors here
        res.render('home', {
            data: jsonFiles
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: also using using the request module can simplify a lot of the http code in your example https://github.com/mikeal/request

Comment: I was recently thinking that there should be a module like jQuery's .ajax, since a lot of people have asked about how to do requests through express. That modules seems to be as easy to use.